# Spring Integration: unidentified error message when using SOLACE

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a Spring Integration application which is using Solace as the message broker. The application is working - messages are received on queues and then correctly placed on topics - yet the following error message is being thrown when a message is created. Am trying to figure out why this is occurring.

```
03:31:12.479 [taskExecutor-8] WARN  o.s.i.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper - failed to map Message header 'JMS_Solace_TopicSequenceNumber' to JMS property
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property SOLACE_JMS_PROP_TOPIC_SEQUENCE_NUMBER is not settable on a message
    at com.solacesystems.jms.message.SolMessage.setObjectProperty(SolMessage.java:486) ~[sol-jms-6.0.0.146.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.java:131) [spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.java:53) [spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler$HeaderMappingMessagePostProcessor.postProcessMessage(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:162) [spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$8.createMessage(JmsTemplate.java:656) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:565) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:546) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:543) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:653) [spring-jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.send(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:142) [spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(JmsSendingMessageHandler.java:112) [spring-integration-jms-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) [spring-integration-core-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115) [spring-integration-core-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:52) [spring-integration-core-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) [spring-integration-core-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52) [spring-integration-core-2.2.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_06]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_06]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_06]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you decompile `solacesystems` classes and take a look which `properties` are appropriate to set onto `SolMessage`? Do you configure your own `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` or use `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` as is?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SOLACE, but it sounds like there is a read-only property on the inbound message. By default, all properties are made available as SI headers and, similarly, we try to map to SI headers to JMS properties (if they are simple types).

This is just a WARNing - you can

- Ignore it - set the log level for the mapper to ERROR
- Use a custom header mapper to skip it
- Set an outboundPrefix on the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` so that the property gets a different name
- Add a `<header-filter/>` before the outbound adapter to remove it